# Elastic search keyword not matching

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I,am doing an search operation in elastic search DB.What i need is that if i give keyword 'react' for search it should give only results matching keyword 'react' also if keyword is 'react-router' ,result should contain only 'react-router'.
The problem is that if i give search keyword 'react' , results matching 'react-router' keyword is also retrieved.
Is there any better option than match-phrase , i tried regexp and wildcard but no use.
how to solve this

```
`const searchTags = (tag) => {
  const answerPush = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.search({
      index : constants.QUESTIONNAIRE_INDEX,
      type : constants.QUESTIONS_TYPE,
      scroll : constants.SCROLL,
      body : {
        query : {
          match_phrase : {
            tags : tag
          }
        }
      }
    },
    function getMoreUntilDone(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      } else {
        res.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit) {
          answerPush.push(hit._source);
        });
        if (res.hits.total > answerPush.length) {
          client.scroll({
            scrollId: res._scroll_id,
            scroll: constants.SCROLL
          }, getMoreUntilDone);
        } else {
          const answerArray = [];
          answerPush.map(val => {
            answerArray.push(val);
          });
          const result = {
            questions: answerArray
          };
          resolve(result);
        }
      }});
  });
};
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To search by exact match, you must use term query.

and it's probably working well in your case, just keep in mind, Elasticsearch will analyse/index your strings and for example react-redux will be "splitted" in two keywords because of the "-"

you need to configure the strategy in your mapping:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-search-for-terms-containing-hyphen-on--all-field/81335

Comment: You need to use a custom analyzer to say to ES "please, don't split my string on '-'" to be able to search on the full string
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Answer (score -1):

Use term query instead of match phrase query

```
const searchTags = (tag) => {
  const answerPush = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.search({
      index : constants.QUESTIONNAIRE_INDEX,
      type : constants.QUESTIONS_TYPE,
      scroll : constants.SCROLL,
      body : {
        query : {
          term : {
            tags : tag
          }
        }
      }
    },
    function getMoreUntilDone(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      } else {
        res.hits.hits.forEach(function(hit) {
          answerPush.push(hit._source);
        });
        if (res.hits.total > answerPush.length) {
          client.scroll({
            scrollId: res._scroll_id,
            scroll: constants.SCROLL
          }, getMoreUntilDone);
        } else {
          const answerArray = [];
          answerPush.map(val => {
            answerArray.push(val);
          });
          const result = {
            questions: answerArray
          };
          resolve(result);
        }
      }});
  });
};
```

Comment: still not working ,showing empty results for keyword 'react-redux'

Comment: @rahulmr are there any documents with tags exactly equal to "react-redux"?

Comment: @rahulmr Can you add mapping for tags?